# how to center element inside stacked icon

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I have the following snippet of code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="fa-stack" style="width: auto;">
      <!-- The icon that will wrap the number -->
      <span class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></span>
      <!-- a strong element with the custom content, in this case a number -->
      <strong class="fa-stack-1x">1</strong>
    </span>
  This is a sentence.
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

This is from a larger project (simplified the code), and I need to have the `style="width:auto"` on the parent span class.

Without removing the `style="width:auto"`, I am trying to achieve three things:

- center the "1" in the box
- make the 1 on the same line as "This is a sentence"
- make the "This is a sentence appear next to the box instead of overlapping inside it.

This would look similar to the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjP3Y.png), except that the 1 isn't on the same line as "This is a sentence" - would anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace class `fa-stack-2x` with `fa-2x` in `span.fa`

`fa-stack-2x` class has `position:absolute` so that text is overlay it

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="fa-stack" style="width: auto;">
      <!-- The icon that will wrap the number -->
      <span class="fa fa-square-o fa-2x"></span>
      <!-- a strong element with the custom content, in this case a number -->
      <strong class="fa-stack-1x">1</strong>
    </span>
  This is a sentence.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or You can do this without using font-awesome

```css
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>        
      <span class="square">1</span>
      This is a sentence.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The 1 is outside the box?

Comment: I was looking to have the 1 inside the middle of the box and on the same line as the other text.

Comment: In snippet it's looks ok

Comment: the snippet shows the "1" outside the box for me, is it showing inside the box for you?